# SAS-Macro-exponential function

Tags: sas

I have problems creating this macro in SAS:

Write macro to print and plot the exponential function of a given “base” starting in the range “start” – to – “end” calculated by increment “incr”.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Ariel

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow.  If you have a particular issue you should specify what particular thing you don't understand, but if you don't understand the problem at all you need to find a different resource.  Please see the [faq] for more information about writing a good StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

The below will give you want you're after.

```
%macro expplot(base=, from=, to=, inc=) ;
    data dset ;
        base=&base;
        do xvar=&from to &to by &inc;
           yvar=base**xvar ;
           put base= xvar= yvar= ;
           output ;
        end ;
    run ;

    proc sgplot data=dset ;
        series x=xvar y=yvar;
        title "Exponential plot of &base";
    run ;
%mend expplot;
%expplot(base=10, from=0, to=10,  inc=1) ;
%expplot(base=2,  from=0, to=100, inc=2) ;
```

By assigning base to &base at the start it only needs to be resolved one time - otherwise you could just pass the parameter straight into `&base**xvar`